# Android SQLiteDatabase query with WHERE clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLiteDatabase called "Database". In it there is a table called "Pics". In the table there are three columns as follows, DrawableName TEXT,DrawableReference INTEGER,PictureRating REAL. I want to query my database with an integer that I expect to be in the DrawableReference column. I want to do this so that I can get the corresponding DrawableName and PictureRating from the same row. What is wrong with my query?

```
public class EditItemActivity extends Activity {
    EditText textField=null;
    RatingBar ratingBar=null;
    SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    Cursor dbCursor=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Integer imageId=intent.getIntExtra("imageId",-1);
        if(imageId==-1){
            return;
        }
        String id=imageId.toString(); //not used right now
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_item_layout);
        db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("Database",this.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        String selection="DrawableReference = ?";
        String[] whereClause={id.toString()};
        dbCursor=db.query("Pics",null,selection,whereClause,null,null,null);//get the row where the correct DrawableReference integer is found
        textField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
        ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.image_rating_bar);
        if(dbCursor.moveToFirst()){
            textField.setText(dbCursor.getString(0)); //this never happens
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try this  `String[] whereClause={imageId.toString()};`

Comment: or try as per my answer but make sure your id is not null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
    Cursor dbCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DrawableName,PictureRating FROM Pics Where DrawableReference='"+ id.toString()+"'", null);

    if(dbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    textField.setText(dbCursor.getString(0)); 
    }
```

Or

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("Pics", new String[] { "DrawableName",
        "PictureRating" }, "DrawableReference =?",
        new String[] {id}, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
  textField.setText(cursor.getString(0)); 
}
```

Comment: Turns out I was passing the id of the imageview, rather than the id of the image in the imageview!

Comment: Always check for `moveTo...` return value before trying to access row data.

Answer (score 0):

Query looks OK. Have you verified that there is a row with the specified DrawableReference is present?

On the rooted device or emulator you can do this by doing:

```
adb shell
su
cd /data/data/com.your.package/databases
sqlite3 your_db_name.db
```

And then doing the regular SQL queries.

You should also refrain from using constant column indices in `Cursor.getFoo()` calls. As far as I know the current implementation returns the columns in the same order as specified in projection. or in the order of column definitions in CREATE TABLE statement when projection is null, but this is not guaranteed by the API. You should use `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("column_name"))` instead.